# StackOverflow Error AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

This is the code I am getting a StackOverflow error for. I am not entirely sure what is wrong with it. The code is plug and play, so u cna plug it in and test it your self. Can somebody please Help me with it? I am basically genereating 2 different objects from one array and trying to get rid of the object that gets clicked on and, then I put that object into a different array.

```
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var eating_breakfast:Sprite;
var walking:Sprite;
var swimming:Sprite;
var art:Sprite;
var choices:Array = new Array ();

//Sprite Creation
eating_breakfast = new Sprite ();
eating_breakfast.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
eating_breakfast.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
eating_breakfast.graphics.endFill();
eating_breakfast.x = 50;
eating_breakfast.y = 50;


walking = new Sprite ();
walking.graphics.beginFill(0xC3266C);
walking.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
walking.graphics.endFill();
walking.x = 100;
walking.y = 100;


swimming = new Sprite ();
swimming.graphics.beginFill(0x48AFD1);
swimming.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
swimming.graphics.endFill();
swimming.x = 150;
swimming.y = 150;


art = new Sprite ();
art.graphics.beginFill(0xafdb44);
art.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
art.graphics.endFill();
art.x = 200;
art.y = 200;

//adding sprites into array
choices.push( eating_breakfast);
choices.push(walking);
choices.push(swimming);
choices.push(art);


var indexcount = 0;
var randomize:Number;
var storageArray: Array = new Array ();
civilizedorder();
randomizedorder();
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,switchpic);

//pick the target generated object
function switchpic(t:MouseEvent)
{
    //for index count
    // this works as a target so if your mouse target is the object generated by indexcount this will initiate
    if (t.target == choices[indexcount])
    {
        storageArray.push(choices[indexcount]);
        removeChild(choices [indexcount]);
        removeChild(choices [randomize]);
        choices.splice(indexcount,1);
        goNext();

    }
    // for randomize
    if (t.target == choices[randomize])
    {
        // this works as a target so if your mouse target is the object generated by randomize this will initiate
        storageArray.push(choices[randomize]);
        removeChild(choices [indexcount]);
        removeChild(choices [randomize]);
        choices.splice(randomize,1);
        indexcount++;

        goNext();
    }
}

//generates the index count object
function civilizedorder()
{
    trace("The Index count is" + indexcount);
    addChild(choices [indexcount]);
    choices[indexcount].x = 300;


}
trace("The number of choices in the choice array is " + choices.length);
//generates the randomized object
function randomizedorder()
{

    randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    trace("the random number is" + randomize);
    if (randomize == indexcount )
    {
        randomizedorder();
    }
    else
    {
        addChild(choices [randomize]);
    }

}


function goNext()
{
    trace("The storagearray has " + (storageArray.length));
    if (choices.length < 0 || choices.length > 0)
    {
        if (indexcount > choices.length-1)
        {
            indexcount = choices.length - 1;
        }
        civilizedorder();
        randomizedorder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow means you have too much recursion. In this case, that's probably in the `randomizedorder` function when `choices.length` is 1 and `indexcount` is 0 (i.e. the first call of `goNext`), it makes an infinite loop.

You need to re-think the structure of this program. Avoid recursion wherever possible. Loops are better, but you don't need them either; to fix that one function:

```
randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (choices.length - 1));
if (randomize >= indexcount ) {
    randomize ++;
}
```

You'll still probably get bizarre results since it isn't being called as you expect, but the stack overflow should go away.

Comment: oh I see thanks very much :D I was really going around in circles. This made it clearer.